# SSH Tunneling what factor impacts forwarding failure?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I have been exploring ssh tunneling, and not experiencing what i wanted.

Firstly, I tried with my local machine with local port forwarding which worked fine.

```
1) ssh -L 8080:localhost:8081 localhost
2) nc -l 8081

3) echo "Super User" | nc localhost 8080
```

Now, 8080 traffic is forwarded to 8081, as a result, "SuperUser" string is printed from "**nc -l 8081**" command.

**Fair Enough.**

Now, I tried forwarding to webserver.

```
ssh -L 8080:www.techgig.com:80 localhost
```

It worked well.  But, when i tried

```
ssh -L 8080:www.medium.com:80 localhost
```

I received below error:

```
Error 1003 Direct IP access not allowed
```

**Question:**

So, my question is what is the factor that impacts few websites works and few of them doesn't work. At the end it is all about just forwarding the data right?. Please Kindly clarify

Comment: It depends on the configuration of httpd. It may accept `Host: localhost` or may not.
Use localhost:8080 as http_proxy, then all sites will be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 1) You mean the configuration of httpd is at "medium.com" for example right?. 2)  I am afraid, i do not know how to make localhost:8080 as http_proxy, can u help me please?

Comment: in linux terminal: `export http_proxy="http://localhost:8080/"`. With any graphical browser: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just forwading the data. The problem is, **you're giving it different data** to forward, compared to when you connect directly.

Take a look at any HTTP request in Wireshark. You'll see that practically all of them have a `Host:` header saying which domain name they want to reach. This is necessary because TCP/IP connections *do not* automatically forward the hostname used – the Medium webserver does not know that you used `www.medium.com` to reach it *unless* the HTTP request tells it that.

So when you're accessing `http://www.medium.com` in a browser, it sends a HTTP request with `Host: www.medium.com` in it, because that's what you entered.

But when you set up a forwarding and try to access `http://localhost:8080`, well, the browser also sends `Host: localhost` because that's what you entered. The web server has no idea about your forwarding – all it knows is your IP address and the HTTP headers – so it correctly complains that its configuration does not list such a domain.

---

As for the http_proxy suggestion: if you create a forwarding at a web server, and try to use it as a HTTP proxy, it'll only let you access sites on *that* web server.

While technically it could work, nearly all webservers deny proxying for *security* reasons. (Just imagine if that was allowed – not only the webserver would let you into the datacenter's private network, you could also spam the whole world and pretend that the webserver did it.)